# microtype and french typography

Tags: spacing, typography, microtype, french, frenchspacing

In french, we put spaces before characters `: ! ; ?` when we **type the text**. For instance, we will type

```
Que fait-on ? On met un espace avant les deux points : comme cela.
```

If I do so and use `microtype`, the spacing in the generated `pdf` file is not the right one. See the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true, kerning=french]{microtype}

\begin{document}
 
  Voici ce qui se passe quand on met un signe \og{}deux~points\fg{} 
 avec le package \og{}microtype\fg{} : il semble que ça ne marche pas ! 
 Un autre essai : est-ce que cela marche ?
  \bigskip 

  \textbf{But what happens if I type my text following the 
 English typographic rules?}
  \bigskip 

  Voici ce qui se passe quand on met un signe \og{}deux~points\fg{} 
 avec le package \og{}microtype\fg{}: il semble que ça ne marche pas! 
 Un autre essai: est-ce que cela marche?
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Hence:

- **How can I  use `microtype` and type my text the french way?**

---

Note: here is the result without `microtype`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
%\usepackage[babel=true, kerning=french]{microtype}

\begin{document}
 
  Voici ce qui se passe quand on met un signe \og{}deux~points\fg{} 
 avec le package \og{}microtype\fg{} : 
 il semble que ça ne marche pas ! Un autre essai : est-ce que cela marche ?
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I personally think that this is a pain to read. Do you know why it is done like that in France?

Comment: When you are French, you feel it is the way it should be for all languages!!

Comment: @Ingo A discussion on [orthotypographie.fr](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-II/point_cardinal-proverbe.html#Ponctuation) suggests that it prevents changing the *shape* of the word, which helps reading. And then, there is use of habit. By the way, Colas, may I suggest using non-breaking spaces before “high” punctuation? It makes much more sense and, when writing email, you’ll need to do it anyway. Any text editor which can handle LaTeX should be able to insert the proper “~” when you type a non-breaking space when correctly set up.

Comment: @Édouard Doesn't `babel` transform automatically theses spaces to non-breaking spaces?

Comment: It probably prevents line breaks before “:;?!”. But I just find it way easier to always type “non-breaking space; question mark; space“ whatever software I’m in rather than type “space; question mark; space” in LaTeX only. But, as I said, this is just a suggestion.

Comment: Note: as recommended by `babel-french` documentation, don't use `\og text \fg{}` but `\frquote{text}`. You can also load the `csquote` package and use `\enquote{text}`...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to use `kerning=french`, then you need to disable the punctuation settings made by `babel` *and* leave no space before punctuation symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\frenchbsetup{AutoSpacePunctuation=false}
\usepackage[babel=true, kerning=french]{microtype}

\begin{document}

Voici ce qui se passe quand on met un signe \og{}deux~points\fg{}
avec le package \og{}microtype\fg{}: il semble que ça ne marche pas!
Un autre essai: est-ce que cela marche?

\bigskip

\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
But what happens if I type my text following the
English typographic rules?
\end{otherlanguage*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that for disabling the humongous space before punctuation used in French typography when using another language you have to tell LaTeX you want to temporarily change the rules.

Alternatively, don't use `kerning=french`; you can type a space before punctuation or not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}

\begin{document}

Voici ce qui se passe quand on met un signe \og{}deux~points\fg{}
avec le package \og{}microtype\fg{}: il semble que ça ne marche pas!
Un autre essai: est-ce que cela marche?

\bigskip

Voici ce qui se passe quand on met un signe \og{}deux~points\fg{}
avec le package \og{}microtype\fg{} : il semble que ça ne marche pas !
Un autre essai : est-ce que cela marche ?

\end{document}
```

[image]

My eyes will never get used to see such monstrosities perpetrated by the French. `;-)`

Comment: Thanks! I want to type a space before `: ? ! ;`. So, I will not use `kerning=french`. Will I loose a lot doing so?

Comment: @Colas I don't think so; the `kerning` feature seemed promising, but it isn't really working.

Comment: Great to put some *complete* code in your answer.

Comment: Don't work with `«` and `»` unicode characters instead of `\og` and `\fg` (a pity, since in Linux are easily typed with `AltGr+z` and `AlrGr+x`).

Comment: @Fran Say `\usepackage{newunicodechar}`; then `\newunicodechar{«}{\og}` and `\newunicodechar{»}{\fg}` should do.

Comment: @egreg Nice, now it is easier make « French monstrosities » `:)`

Comment: @egreg - You do know what Goethe remarked about mathematicians and the French, right?

Comment: @Mico Of course! “Mathematicians are like Frenchmen: whatever you say to them they translate into their own language, and forthwith it is something entirely different.”

Comment: @egreg: Interestingly, classic Italian typography has similar spacing rules (perhaps not so much space, though). A possible reference for that is Serra's Regole editoriali, tipografiche & redazionali (http://www.libraweb.net/result1.php?chiave=2393&valore=sku). I personally find it quite charming, if not but for humanistic studies.

Comment: @gsl I believe that this book owes much to French typography. Too much, I should say. ;-)

Comment: @egreg A designer of course can afford choices (ie to break from tradition, and how much). A "LaTeX typesetter", having to respect precise specs from the publisher, perhaps has less choice. Thank you so much for the perspective, it is always valuable coming from you (and looking forward to GuIT in Verona).