# Why are not all microtyping features enabled by default?

Tags: microtype

According to the microtype manual, Kerning, Spacing and Tracking are not enabled by default in `pdftex` (>= 1.4). What are the reasons for this?

[image: Manual]

Comment: Many classes/packages don't have all possible options enabled. In that sense, there's nothing _odd_ about `microtype`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These three features are not enabled by default for different reasons:

- The *extra kerning* feature (changing the side bearings of characters) is mainly useful for typesetting traditions where certain characters are to be separated by a space, eg. the French style of punctuation. Moreover, there are competing implementations of this (`babel`, `csquotes` ...), which would interfere. And finally, these other implementations are [probably preferable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142397/7674).
- The *spacing* feature (changing the inter-word space depending on the preceding character) has been experimental from the outset, its implementation in `pdftex` never complete. The benefit of this feature seems negligible (probably because TeX's hyphenation algorithm, even combined with font expansion, is already good enough), and may even have adverse side effects (space factors will be ignored, for example).
- The *tracking* feature (changing the inter-letter space) is the one candidate which one could argue should be enabled by default for small caps. But then again, letterspacing is a matter of taste to a higher degree than protrusion or expansion, and a decision that should be taken deliberately, in particular, as @cfr comments, as the optimal letterspacing would be font-dependent.

In general, `microtype` only enables those features by default that can be expected to unconditionally improve the typesetting without being immediately visible. The rest is left to the user.

Comment: You might add that the effects of altering spacing, for example, depend on what the spacing is to begin with and that depends on the font. So the spacing and tracking features are likely to be font-dependent. But the default feature set needs to improve things regardless of the particular font used. Fine-tuning files can then set better defaults for particular fonts, if available. For example, the file for Computer Modern adjusts interword spacing for certain characters in certain contexts. So the defaults here are different.

Comment: @cfr D'accord for tracking. The different spacing settings for CMR are mainly to work around the fact that space factors are ignored.