# Can I enable letter expansion with Xelatex somehow?

Tags: xetex, microtype

I have a two column which I want to compile with Xelatex. However, I get a lot of over/underfull hbox'es. I use the microtype and fontspec package. The former can only performe protrusion with Xelatex. Is there a way to use expansion with Xelatex (not necessarily with microtype)?

I'm aware of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215679/why-are-not-all-microtyping-features-enabled-by-default) about microtype, however it is quite old.

Comment: Would font expansion solve your problem? Did you test it with lualatex?